# How can I generate .csproj Project file only in C# Console App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0, dotnet-cli, dotnet-new

I already have a `Program.cs` in the folder/directory and no other files.

When I do `dotnet new console`, it won't let me create it unless I use `--force` to overwrite the `Program.cs`. I think I just need to create `.csproj` project file to build, run and debug it.

Is there a `dotnet new console` with option to skip `Program.cs` creation?

Otherwise, I will need to make a new directory and create `dotnet new console` and then I have to replace the auto-generated `Program.cs` with my `Program.cs`.

Answer (score 5):

> Otherwise, I will need to make a new directory and create dotnet new console and then I have to replace the auto-generated Program.cs with my Program.cs.

Well there's a simpler option than that:

- Rename `Program.cs` to `OldProgram.cs`
- Run `dotnet new console`
- Rename `OldProgram.cs` to `Program.cs`

Alternatively, just write the `csproj` file by hand - it's really simple. The default on my machine is:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

You could just copy/paste that into the new file...

Comment: Yes. I could do that. What I did was I copy/cut the code in the original `Program.cs` and then `dotnet new console --force`. And I just paste the code in the new `Program.cs`. :D